# Filter dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe as below where the columns may have the presence of characters other than Eglish A-Z and numbers 0-9

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Jo!hn Benjam^in', '10th Avenueś'], ['Nick', '15$th Cross Str&eet'], ['Juli@e', 'Hackinson ro))ad'],['Vinやあcent','Main Stree吨']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Address'])
df
```

How to spot all the unwanted characters other than the A-Z and 0-9 in each column as below?

**Whitespace can be ignored

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
df['Address_OP'] = df['Address'].str.extractall(r'([^A-Za-z0-9\s])').groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
df['Name_OP'] = df['Name'].str.extractall(r'([^A-Za-z0-9\s])').groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
df
```

Output:

```
              Name              Address Address_OP Name_OP
0  Jo!hn Benjam^in         10th Avenueś          ś     !,^
1             Nick  15$th Cross Str&eet        $,&     NaN
2           Juli@e     Hackinson ro))ad        ),)       @
3        Vinやあcent          Main Stree吨          吨     や,あ
```